# Error using fitdist with truncated distributions

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am trying to fit a certain truncated distribution to a data set. For example, for a lognormal distribution, I define the density function of the truncated distribution as:

```
dtlnorm <- function(x, meanlog, sdlog,low) 
  dlnorm(x,meanlog,sdlog)/(1-plnorm(low,meanlog,sdlog))* (x >= low)
```

where low is the truncation point.

My data is the following vector

```
Data <- c(1068295.00589834, 1406446.49289834, 1540330.78489834, 1152321.94489834, 
3108649.66189834, 3718417.97089834, 2981945.18089834, 4552923.31989834, 
5747260.98289834, 2105461.57989834, 1044515.95889834, 1133641.75289834, 
3847920.72789834, 2536441.02989834, 3073854.15789834, 1591039.28389834, 
2592446.73289834, 4989152.55189834, 2426457.45489834, 120265066.499898, 
6888222046.1999, 1092811.87089834, 3440123.51689834, 74684298.1398983, 
1475038.27689834, 1124226.39489834, 11739544.5798983, 1187688.74489834, 
1023193.88789834, 18784663.9698983)
```

To fit the distribution, I write:

```
fitdist(Data,distr="tlnorm",method="mle",start = list(meanlog=0,sdlog=0),fix.arg = list(low=100))
```

But the following error appears:

```
Error in fitdist(Data, distr = "tlnorm", method = "mle", start = list(meanlog = 0,  : 
the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
            with the error code 100
```

I do not know what is happening. Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: In the help pages it says you need a `ptlnorm` and `qtlnorm` functions as well ie distribution and quantile. Does say "A character string "name" naming a distribution for which the corresponding density function dname, the corresponding distribution function pname and the corresponding quantile function qname must be defined, or directly the density function." Looks like you can submit `dtlnorm` without the quotes, maybe that will work e.g. `distr=dtlnorm`. Might still need the other functions though

Comment: I have tried both defining p and q functions and writing dist=dtlnorm, but the same error is produced.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557022/error-code-100-fitting-exp-distribution-using-fitdist-in-r) relevant?

Comment: I had read it and it does not solve my problem. The same error appears

Comment: Are you able to add your data by running `dput` function, please?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003362/problems-fitting-log-pearson-iii-in-r/15569722#15569722